# JS duplicando ao enviar registro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma aplicação com Modal do bootstrap, porém ao enviar os dados com o botão ele duplica o evento, segue o js com a duplicação.

```
$(document).on('click', '.form-delete', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form=$(this);
    $('#title_delete').val($(this).data('title'));
    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        .on('click', '#delete-btn', function(){
            alert($form);
        });
});
```

O funcionamento é o seguinte, se fechar a modal e abrir novamente, ao clicar no botão delete e enviar os dados ele envia os dados do modal anterior e o atual.

Segue o link do teste https://jsfiddle.net/308s2ftk/3/

Comment: Pode descrever melhor como é feito o envio? Talvez seja necessário o html para poder visualizar os forms.

Comment: vou fazer ele funcionando e postar

Comment: Coloquei o link do teste, repare que se fechar o modal e abrir novamente, clicar em apagar ele vai duplicar o evento

Comment: Tenta fazer o bind assim: `$(document).unbind('click').on('click' ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separe os eventos e declare uma variável global pra popular o form:

```
var $form;

$(document).on('click', '.form-delete', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);
    $('#title_delete').val($(this).data('title'));
    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
});

$(document).on('click', '#delete-btn', function(){
    alert($form);
});
```

O que ocorre é que no seu código toda vez que você clica em .form-delete você anexa um novo evento de click no #delete-btn. Por isso vai gerando um aumento progressivo de alerts.

Seu fiddle atualizado: https://jsfiddle.net/308s2ftk/9/

Comment: Perfeito, nossa estava quebrando a cabeça e resolvi perguntar, obrigado